# awk: data missed while parsing file

Tags: shell, awk, sh

I have written a script to parse hourly log files to extract "CustomerId, Marketplace, StartTime, and DealIdClicked" data. The log file structure is like so:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Size=0 bytes
scheme=https
StatusCode=302
RequestId=request_Id_X07
CustomerId=XYZCustomerId
Marketplace=MarketPlace
StartTime=1592931599.986
Program=Unknown
Info=sub-page-type=desktop:Deals_Content_DealIdClicked_0002,sub-page-CSMTags=UTF-8
Counters=sub-page-type=desktop:Deals_Content_DealIdClicked_0002=3,sub-page-CSMTags=Encoding:UTF-8
EOE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the script I have written to parse the log.

```
function readServiceLog() {
  local _logfile="$1"
  local _csvFile="$2"

  local _logFileName=$(getLogFileName "$_logfile")

  parseLogFile "$_logfile" "$_csvFile"

  echo "$_logFileName" >>"$SCRIPT_PATH/excludeFile.txt"
}

# Function to match regex and extract required data.
function parseLogFile() {
  local _logfile=$1
  local _csvFile=$2

  zcat <"$_logfile" | awk -v csvFilePath="$_csvFile" '
  BEGIN {
    customerIdRegex="^CustomerId="
    marketplaceIdRegex="^MarketplaceId="
    startTimeRegex="^StartTime="
    InfoRegex="^Info="
    dealIdRegex = "Deals_Content_DealIdClicked_"
    EOERegex="^EOE$"
    delete RECORD
  }
  {
    logLine=$0
    if (match(logLine,InfoRegex)) {
      after = substr(logLine,RSTART+RLENGTH);
      if(match(after, dealIdRegex)) {
        afterDeal = substr(after,RSTART+RLENGTH);
        dealId = substr(afterDeal, 1, index(afterDeal,",")-1)
        RECORD[0] = dealId
      }
    }

    if (match(logLine,customerIdRegex)) {
      after = substr(logLine,RSTART+RLENGTH);
      customerid = substr(after, 1, length(after))
      RECORD[1] = customerid
    }

    if (match(logLine,startTimeRegex)) {
      after = substr(logLine,RSTART+RLENGTH);
      startTime = substr(after, 1, length(after))
      RECORD[2] = startTime
    }

    if (match(logLine,marketplaceIdRegex)) {
      after = substr(logLine,RSTART+RLENGTH);
      marketplaceId = substr(after, 1, length(after))
      RECORD[3] = marketplaceId
    }

    if (match(logLine,EOERegex)) {
      if(length(RECORD) == 4) {
        printf("%s,%s,%s,%s\n", RECORD[0],RECORD[1],RECORD[2],RECORD[3]) >> csvFilePath
      }
      delete RECORD
    }
  }'
}

function processHourlyFile() {
  local _currentProcessingFolder=$1
  local _outputFolder=$(getOutputFolderName) //getOutputFolderName function is from util class.
  mkdir -p "$_outputFolder"
  local _csvFileName="$_outputFolder/${_currentProcessingFolder##*/}.csv"

  for entry in "$_currentProcessingFolder"/*; do
    if [[ "$entry" == *"$SERVICE_LOG"* ]]; then
      readServiceLog "$entry" "$_csvFileName"
    fi
  done
}

# Main execution to spawn new processes for parallel parsing.
function main() {
  local _processCount=1
  for entry in $INPUT_LOG_PATH/*; do
    processHourlyFile $entry &
    pids[${_processCount}]=$!
  done

  printInfo

  # wait for all pids
  for pid in ${pids[*]}; do
    wait $pid
  done
}

main
printf '\nFinished!\n'
```

Expected output:

A comma separated file.

```
0002,XYZCustomerId,1592931599.986,MarketPlace
```

### Problem

The script spawns 24 processes to parse 24-hour logs for an entire day. After parsing the files, I  verified the count of record, and some time it doesn’t match with the original log file record count.

I am stuck on this from the last two days with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is this tagged powershell?

Comment: For the sample input shown, what is the output that you want?  Also, is the sample input one of the records that gives you problems ("doesn’t match")?  If not, [edit] your question and add at least one of the problem-causing records.

Comment: Hey John, I updated the question and add sample output. Its not like its failing for one or two records, sometime the file is getting parsed correctly and I have all correct result and sometime it misses some data. I think their is some problem managing multiple processes.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
awk -F= '    
    {
        a[$1]=$2
    }
    /^Info/ {
        sub(/.*DealIdClicked_/, "")
        sub(/,.*/, "")
        print $0, a["CustomerId"], a["StartTime"], a["Marketplace"]
        delete a
    }' OFS=, filename
```

When run on your input file, the above produces the desired output:

```
0002,XYZCustomerId,1592931599.986,MarketPlace
```

#### How it works

- `-F=` tells awk to use `=` as the field separator on input.
- `{ a[$1]=$2 }` tells awk to save the second field, `$2`, in associative array `a` under the key `$1`.
- `/^Info/ { ... }`  tells awk to perform the commands in curly braces whenever the line starts with `Info`.  Those commands are:

  - `sub(/.*DealIdClicked_/, "")` removes all parts of the line up to and including `DealIdClicked_`.
  - `sub(/,.*/, "")` tells awk to remove from what's left of the line everything from the first comma to the end of the line.

    The remainder of the line, still called `$0`, is the "DealId" that we want.
  - `print $0, a["CustomerId"], a["StartTime"], a["Marketplace"]` tells awk to print the output that we want.
  - `delete a` this deletes array `a` so we start  over clean on the next record.
- `OFS=,` tells awk to use a comma as the field separator on output.